Row.cells not in the same order as actual spreadsheet?
Im using an older version 2.5.2 and when I step into my code, 
I am attempting to using row.GetCell(N) where N is the column index.
This seems ok when pulling the first few cells of a row.  However, I noticed after the first few cells, the next cell I was trying to grab would have been at index 11 (just viewing the spreadsheet), yet its been "shifted" somehow at runtime.
In Visual Studio, I opened the local window and view the row.cells collection, and sure enough, the cell im trying to grab is NOT at the index that is related to its position in the spreadsheet when its opened.  Am I going crazy or just missing something?

Had a similar issue with a file I was working on (not created by me), the problem was in the file npoi was seeing cells not visible when I opened the sheet I don't know if they are hidden or what, anyway I just copied the data to a new file and it worked as expected.

Yep, that worked!  very strange.  I did NOT have any hidden columns, but I just copied the data into a new spreadsheet and things just worked and the cell was where I expected it to be.  Thanks!

Neither did I have any hidden columns, till now I didn't know what the problem was. You are welcome.

I had a similar issue with a file I was working on (not created by me), the problem was in the file npoi was seeing cells that were not visible when I opened the sheet I don't know if they are hidden or what, anyway I just copied the data to a new file and it worked as expected.
